# Error with office 2010 Macros

Tags: windows, macros, word-2010

I have a client trying to run a Macro in Word 2010. It used to work on their windows XP machines, but since we've migrated them to windows 7, the have issues. Both used office 2010, and the files they need to call exist. I'm very unfamiliar with office macros, and I don't know any syntax for it.

When they try to run it, they get the error 5941, saying an object can't be found. The debugger highlights "Windows("document1").Activate.

If you delete that line, it repeats the error for the next line. Am I missing something?

```
Sub JHV()
'
' JHV Macro
'
'

    Windows("document1").Activate
    Windows("document2").Activate
    Windows("document3").Activate
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=12
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=5
End Sub
```

Comment: Are those documents ("document1", ..) open?

Comment: No.From what I'm getting, all they do is hit (ALT+J) to insert a signature at the bottom.

Comment: Then I am very surprised that the code ran to begin with.  Unless their previous setup had hidden documents that opened in the background at startup, and didn't get copied over.

Comment: I was confused too. I think it might be a problem from XP to 7 migration? I'm not sure.